# Tensorflow 2.3.x cudnn failure Windows 10 CUDA 10.1 CUDNN 7.6.5 Anaconda3

Tags: windows, tensorflow, installation, gpu

Running TensorFlow 2.3.x and then stopping and then running it again seems to cause Tensorflow to fail to initialize cudnn. This stopping and starting is unavoidable when fine tuning and debugging pre and post processing. Every time cudnn fails I have to restart my computer. This failure seems to have a 50% probability of happening per run.

My setup is Windows 10, CUDA 10.1 Update 2, CUDNN 7.6.5, Anaconda3 python 3.7/3.6, TensorFlow 2.3.0/2.3.1, NVIDIA RTX2080ti. I followed the exact requirements listed at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu but this is nearly unusable.

I have tried python 3.7, python 3.6, cudnn 7.6.x with CUDA 10.1 original, update 1, and update 2, and TensorFlow 2.2.0. All with the same results. The Tensorflow printout shows that all dlls were successfully loaded including cudnn64_7.dll. Why is this so unstable?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: "dlls were successfully loaded" means nothing.  I don't have a solution for this but I can tell you that.  This is one of those "on the line" issues that might be better served by SuperUser.  Are you writing code?  Is this a programming issue?  You might try there too.

Comment: In the past this error would occur when a dll failed to load. The printout would show that some cuda/cudnn dll failed to load. You could simply run it again and everything would work fine.

I am writing code but TensorFlow and python handle all memory management and handles so I have no control any of these issues unless the problem arises due to a bug in one of the TensorFlow api calls.

I do know that the dlls and header files need to match exactly. TensorFlow specifies cudnn 7.6 and cuda 10.1 but there are 18 permutations that satisfy those requirements and near infinite with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of debugging I have found that the issue isn't with CUDA, CUDNN, TensorFlow, Python, Anaconda but is actually Windows 10.

I had mistakenly joined the Windows Insider program in order to get a Linux Virtual machine working in Windows. That worked but then TensorFlow stopped working properly in Windows. I had read that there were side effects with the insider program and so I reinstalled (That is the only way to get back to a standard version after 10 days or an update). I didn't realize that Windows released a major version update V2004 and thought that I was going back to what I had. So when I went through the install process I downloaded the most recent version of TF and assumed that to be the problem.

I booted up an old computer and ran my code on it fine. Then I noticed the Windows version differences and upgraded my old computer to 2004. Everything still worked. Then I found an ISO of 1909 and installed that on my main computer and everything started working again.

In conclusion, it looks as if Windows 10 V2004 doesn't allow the tools to install properly but upgrading from V1909 to V2004 still works as long as you don't have to reinstall anything. Who knows what will happen when TF supports CUDA 11. Windows 10 V2004 users may have to stick with an older version of TF.